# Overlay text on image

Tags: html, css

I would like to overlay a part of a text over an image with HTML CSS in order to obtain something like this.

[image]

But the best I manage to obtain is this :

[image]

How I can move the text a little bit to the left ?

Below my code :
[image]

Any tips on how to do this ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: can you edit and copy paste your css and html, don't screen shot beacause its impossible to run on our computers

Comment: This may help you put your code direct into your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also,, consider putting hte image in as a background rather than an img, that way you can position the text independently of the image's dimensions.

Comment: It seems your image could be a background image. If this is so and the image contributes very little to the content of the document, check out the css `background` property. Which you would set on the text div to replace the image. This is a helpful resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```css
  body {
      background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9jjg.png");
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      background-color: #fff;
      background-size: 100%;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 42px;
      color: #00ae82;
    }

    p {
      font-size: 21px;
      color: black;
      line-height: 32px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum
  </h1>
  
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas suscipit, ligula ac tempor lacinia, sem ligula rutrum lacus, nec maximus sem augue eu neque. Integer aliquet ligula nunc, vel pellentesque elit condimentum vel. Sed fermentum dolor ex, vitae porta mi venenatis ac. Praesent imperdiet rhoncus fermentum. Vivamus ac dui euismod, convallis erat sed, cursus diam. Fusce vitae justo ornare, placerat elit quis, ornare tellus. Vivamus iaculis lorem in efficitur imperdiet. Proin quis dolor tincidunt, maximus ante vel, ullamcorper leo. Sed urna turpis, dictum vitae accumsan non, suscipit sed lorem. Ut molestie ac lectus id ornare. Nunc id est libero. Vivamus euismod erat vel pharetra pharetra. Donec pulvinar eleifend lorem scelerisque commodo. Nam nibh augue, vulputate vitae dolor et, dapibus mollis dolor.
  </p>

</div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. It is working really well !
But when I tried to send it by email on outlook the background image is not displaying.

Do you know why and how to correct this ?

Comment: I don't really use outlook for that kind of thing, and not sure how it works....maybe try adding the background image inline to the body tag?  `<body style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9jjg.png'); background-repeat: repeat-y;background-color: #fff;background-size: 100%;font-family: sans-serif;">`.